# Obtain and keep a selected value in a dropdownlist serving as option

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, html-select

I am trying to display in my application a dropdownlist which will be used as an "option" list. The user may select an option that will be applicable elsewhere. This data would be persistent as long as the user stays on the page.

Here's the dropdownlist:

```
public class ResultsOptions
{
    public string mStartOption { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> mListOptions { get; set; }

    public ResultsOptions()
    {
        mListOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

This object is then used this way:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SetResults(string _submitButton, string _option)
{
    mOptions.mListOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var option in mListOptions)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mResultOption))
        {
            if (option == mResultOption)
            {
                SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = true,
                    Text = option,
                    Value = option
                };

                mOptions.mStartOption = option;

                mOptions.mListOptions.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = option,
                    Value = option
                };

                mOptions.mListOptions.Add(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mOptions.mStartOption = "";

            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = option,
                Value = option
            };
            mOptions.mListOptions.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return PartialView(mOptions);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SetResults(ResultsOptions _options)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_options.mStartOption))
    {
        mResultOption = _options.mStartOption;

        mOptions.mStartOption = _options.mStartOption;

        var selected = mOptions.mListOptions.First(_x => _x.Value == _options.mStartOption);

        selected.Selected = true;
    }

    return Json(new { Message = "Option saved" } );
}
```

The `mListOptions` is a static list of string containing `Standard` and `Simple`. As you may have guessed, I'm doing a partial view that I render in my layout like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="float-left">
        @Html.ActionLink("Advanced Search", "AdvancedSearch", "Store")
        @Html.ActionLink("Browse Promo Packs", "PackSearch", "Store")
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
         @{
             Html.RenderAction("SetResults", "Store");
         }
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And finally here's the partial view:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.ResultsOptions

<script type="text/javascript">
        $.post("/Store/SetResults/", $('#options').serialize(),
                function(data) {
                    $('#divMessage').html(data.Message);
                });
        </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "options"} ))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(_model => _model.mStartOption, Model.mListOptions, new { @class = "nullify" })
    <input type="submit" name="_submitButton" value="Set"/>
    <div id="divMessage">

    </div>
}
```

So, basically, I want that dropdownlist to be always displayed as an optional list. The value selected will be used later on and will have little to no impact on the display right now.

However I have a problem, when I click on the "Set" button, my view **ONLY** renders the partial view and the rest is flushed. Not what I wanted to do. Can anyone help me out?

**EDIT**

I have been working on some Json results as suggested, but I have the same problem: the result message obtained is the **ONLY** thing that gets displayed afterward.

Comment: What do you want to happen after the set button is clicked?

Comment: Well I want to retain only the selected option. Nothing changes. Later, in another view / action, I will refer on this variable (`mResultOption`) to see which option the user chose.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are returning a `PartialView` in your `POST` method. If you want to retain the whole view and just update a portion of the html, you need to use jQuery.

Edit:

You can return a `JsonResult` from your `POST` action method that gives a success message or something:

```
return Json(new { Message = "Option saved" });
```

You have to submit your form using jquery's ajax post. First assign an id to your submit button

**View**

```
<input type="submit" id="submit-form" name="_submitButton" value="Set"/>
```

then handle the click event in your script by posting the form.

**Script**

```
 $("#submit-form").click(function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      $.post("/Controller/SetResults/", $("#IdOfYourForm").serialize(),
           function(data) {
           $("#divMessage").html(data.Message);
      });
    });
```